# Node.js Generators not triggering

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

es6. I am learning generators introduced in es6. Here is my app.js when i run node app.js nothing prints . No logs are printed. Here is my code

```
        'use strict';
        let sequence;
        const run = generator =>{
          sequence = generator();

        }

        const resume = (val) => {
          sequence.next(val);
        }

        const async = {
          run,
          resume
        }

        const pause = delay => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('++++++PAUSED FOR 500 MS++++++++++');
            async.resume(1000);
          } , delay);
        }
        function* generatorFunction(){
           console.log('start*****          ');
           var value = yield pause(500);
           console.log('middle*****          ' + value);
           value = yield pause(500);
           console.log('end*****          '+ value);
        }

        async.run(generatorFunction);
```

i need help quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to call sequence.next();

```
   const run = generator =>{
      sequence = generator();
      sequence.next();

    }
```

in your run function so that generator can start looking for first yield statement

Comment: Or better, `async.resume(undefined)`.